# Is it possible to intercept the payload of a secure request in plain text?

Tags: security, ssl, encryption, https, request

Consider we run the following request:

```
url="https://secretsub.example.com/secretpath/post.php" 
payload = {'secretmessage1' : 'foo','secretmessage2' : 'bar'}
r = requests.post(url,data=payload,verify=True)
```

The language (python) is just arbitrary but it can be a request on any other language (NodeJs, Java, Php...)

Notice that the url is using **https**, which means that the connection is secured over SSL. Assuming that I compile this program into binary (**.exe**), would it be possible for computer to read the payloads through a software in plain text?

I know that packet sniffing software (like WireShark), will only reveal the domain name (**example.com**) in plain text but not the secrepath nor the payload which will be encrypted.

If I run this code in a web **browser** however (assuming that it is written in Javascript), I will be able to access the payload and the *secretpath* in plain text inside the browser console. I assume that the browser only encrypts it only after the request is logged in its console. But if this code is run outside the browser, is there a way a for the computer host to intercept those data in plain text? (some sort of packet sniffing tools)

Comment: It is almost always possible to see the plaintext of an SSL connection *on the device making the connection*. Sometimes there are logging options to make it easy, other times you will have to do something more elaborate or painful depending on the platform.

Comment: This is security through obscurity. Tools are able to extract strings from you `.exe` and will recover the URL and the payload, and will be able to redo the same query. Also there could be a mandatory HTTPS proxy on the host (like AV software does) which will be able to read all plain text. It depends if your software ships with a specific list of CAs (you are doing `verify=True` this is **great**!) or uses the one from the underlying OS.

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible to see the domain name, the payload and path are encrypted and can only be decrypted by the session key as negotiated between the client and webserver. But malware on your computer could be able to access it, for instance by having access to the memory used by the application or by using an insecure programming library with some kind of backdoor.

Answer (score 0):

What the https is doing is initiating a certificate exchange so your client will recieve a certificate from the server that validates the server is who thay say they are and allows the client to encrypt the data through the channell (network).

The first bit - validating the server is who they claim to be - relies on something called a certificate chain.  The certificate you recieve will have been signed with an issuers private key.  Your client should check this certificate using the issuers public key that you should "already have".

Most operating systems have a list of trusted root certificates.  In windows you can see them in the certificate manager.

Without knowing python - @Patrick Mevzek hints that you can ship a root CA (certificate authority) or use the OS one.  if your using the OS one - you might need to check its going to be there.

I would expect all this to be automatic - its part of the protocol that you've specified i.e. https.  However - you might want to confirm that with a python person.

Most people kind of ignore all this bit - but it is very important.  If you do not validate the certificate then you are susceptabe to a "Man in the Middle" attack or DNS spoofing.

Basically I can issue a cert for secretsub.example.com using a couple of tools on my desktop.  It will not be signed by a valid CA but if you don't check it then I can either place that cert in a proxy (Man in the Middle) - and when you make your requet my proxy will get the real cert from the real server, establish the HTTP connection but issue my cert to your application.  You will then encrypt to my proxy with my cert so I can read your data and then forward it to the real server - and you'll never know!  (Many corporate proxies do exactly this to their employees).

Alternatively if I can change your DNS to point the IP to my server I can do pretty much the same - act as a proxy.

Once that's done the data will then be encrypted accross the network.

So - yes HTTPS will encrypt accross the network - but check the cert is valid.

Obviously as someone points out - the data is in the clear on the client computer - just like it is in your browser now.

Stuart

Comment: About not doing proper certificate validation, this is the canonical paper that should open the eyes of many developers and library developers: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~shmat/shmat_ccs12.pdf

Comment: As for Python and CAs (but it will be the same in any other language, so it really depends at the end of the day on what "SSL" library you use and how you use it), see https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ssl.html#ca-certificates : *If you are going to require validation of the other side of the connection’s certificate, you need to provide a “CA certs” file, filled with the certificate chains for each issuer you are willing to trust. [..] The platform’s certificates file can be used by calling SSLContext.load_default_certs(), [..]*